# 424 error only then file is opened during procedure

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have set Excel to move some info into MS Word document crated from template using ContentControls.

After last update for my Excel is some other parts of the code (changed nothing with connection to code with newfound error), I started to get `"424 error: Object required"` error running my routine for moving info to Word. I am confused because this code had been working before with no error and still works then I have Word file opened. Please help me determine what is wrong with it and why sudden error despite not changing anything?

Here is relevant part of the code:

```
            'this parts checks if my Word document is already opened
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
            On Error GoTo 0

             'if document is closed - opens it (file existence was checked earlier and works as intended)
            If objWord Is Nothing Then
                'opens file
                Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(sPath & NewFileName)
                objWord.Visible = True
            Else 'if Word documents open, checks if it is the right one, if not, opens right one (On error routine) - works as intended
                On Error GoTo WrongFile
                Set objDoc = objWord.Documents(NewFileName)
                On Error Resume Next
            End If

    'this part of the code works then document already open, and fails then it is closed
    'I need to count ContentControls for later use and neatly data moving procedure
    Set ccRepSec = objDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Nauja registracija").Item(1)
    Set existingCC = Word.ContentControl `this line fails with 424 error then document is closed
    For Each existingCC In ccRepSec.Range.ContentControls
        If existingCC.Tag = "VP_pav" Then 'skaiciuoja pagal VP pavadinimo laukeliu kieki
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
    Next existingCC
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to Word Application? Excel VBA does not know what Word object is, if you do not reference (or declare) it in a proper way... You must set a reference to `Microsoft Word ... Object Library`...

Comment: Or use `objWord` instead of `Word`.

Comment: If I use `objWord` I get different error - `438: Object doesn't support this property or method"`. Strange because if Word is already opened everything works fine.

Comment: `ContentControl` is a property of the document... So, that Word object looks not appropriate for doing that. Do you define that `Word` object somewhere in the start of beginning of your code?

Comment: `ContentControls` looks to be an attribute of the document, not of the Word application. You must dig in order to understand what that `Word` wanted to be, I think... At the document level, `ContentControl` does not exist. But `ContentControls` exists...

Comment: Why do you even have that line of code?  On the next line you overwrite `existingCC` as you start the loop.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford: Good point! I stopped myself at understanding what kind of object would it be...

Comment: (Now), I would just comment that line and see what happens...

Comment: Good insight! It is an old code and I have no idea why I put that line in, turns out, that code worked then doc was opened because of `On Error Resume Next` line - it would just ignore that error. I commented this line out and error is fixed. I am just remain baffled why code worked well before...

Comment: @Gexas: I would not be sure that the code previously worked having that line there... Probably, you (or somebody else) tried something and forgot it in an older version. That `ContentControl` is only an object able to iterate `document.ContentControls`. It only could make sense using something like `Set existingCC = ccRepSec.Range.ContentControls(1)`. Or using it for another index, to only check what it returns...